# Align orientation in Pose Mode

Tags: snapping, inverse-kinematics, pose-mode, transform-orientation

I'm trying to do a simple manipulation that I'm doing every day at work as a professionnal animator. My experiance is with Motion Builder and 3dxMax, but I'm learning Blender on spare time.

I just want to align in Translation AND rotation my IK bone to my FK bone in Pose Mode. My ultimate goal is to continu my animation with a precise exchange between IK curve and FK curve when it's time to switch between IK and FK.

I can use the CTRL+S->Cursor To Selected  /AND/ CTRL+S->Selection To Cursor to align in position my IK bone, but what can I do for the rotation? I cant eyeball this, it will create so much trubble down the road...

[image: My IK that I want to align on the FK]

[image: My Translation align using the Cursor (rotaiton is still the same)]

[image: The actual rotation that I want to match on my FK foot.]

Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: I've searched a lot on the web to find my answer trust me... I may have not look at the right place. I find this question so dum that I couldn't imagine not finding a solution somewhere!! And yet, here I am.... asking how to do a routine task that is as simple as starting a car... but that Blender car won't cease to trick me....

Comment: You can use Rigify, it has IK/FK snap button. If you want to use your own rig though, you would probably need to use a script for that.

Comment: Thank you Mzidare for pointing me at this tool. I should have done more research before starting my own rigg. Since I'm not that good with Python, I'll restart my rigg and animations......

Hard life lesson. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since I dont realy know how to make Mzidare answer in comment the real answer to my question, here is his reply:

«You can use Rigify, it has IK/FK snap button. If you want to use your own rig though, you would probably need to use a script for that. – Mzidare Sep 2 at 10:22»

Thanks!

Comment: [Elaborate on why the comment is the answer.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/119856/edit)  Where in the UI is the switch?

Answer (score 0):

You can snap any two unconstrained objects and/or bones, provided the snap target doesn't depending on the snapping object, without any addons, with what amounts to three steps:

1. Select the snappee.  Shift select the snapper.  Shift-ctrl-c (add constraint with target) -> copy transforms.
2. On constraint tab (bone constraint tab for bones), find the constraint you just created.  To the right of the influence slider, there is an X button.  Click it.  (What it does is apply visual transform, followed by setting the influence to 0.)
3. Delete the constraint.  (It's not doing anything, but it's still creating a dependency that you don't want.)

As mentioned, this doesn't work if the snapee depends on the snapper.  In that case, you can do it twice: first, create an empty, snap to the snappee as described; second, snap the snapper to that empty as described.

Also as mentioned, the precise way that this works can be affected by other constraints.  Most of the time, it will be fine even with other constraints.  But what you're doing is snapping the base transform, which is then acted upon by other constraints, so there are times when you won't get an actual snap.  (This is potentially doable, but not worth the trouble.)

There are plenty of addons that essentially do this.  The ones I've seen are ineffective in various ways.  (A quick constrain+visual transform, with empty creation and deletion to manage dependencies, has always seemed like an obvious place for an addon author to focus attention, as it would be useful for a lot more than just snapping, and would be more effective than any other "copy transforms" addons I've seen.)